# Issue in creating developer account in India

Tags: android, account

I am developer from India. I completed one app development, i wanted to publish it, but when i tried to create google developer account, to my surprize, India is not present in drop down list of countries while creating wallet account. I went ahead by selecting US and while asking for card number, i provided my debit card number (without spaces), CVV number and address correctly, but it is saying card is not valid, but card is working, still i tried another card, same problem. I could not create developer account. Anybody from India faced this problem? may be due to currency. Does anybody has solution for this?

Comment: I Think there is a work around using google wallet for this prblem

Comment: Thanks Renjith, But this link is about publishig paid app, not creating aacount.

Comment: please check the selected answer on that post they have som interesting stuffs for you

Comment: I am having the same problem , i cant open my developer account in google it declines my IDBI card ? what can i do ? I tried using Entropay as some of the blogs said so , but with it my Google wallet is suspended now and payment is reversed to entropay.

Comment: Google accepts only credit cards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i m late in this discussion but for new people,
i have registered Google play account recently from India n after trying almost all type of cards i found out this,
Almost all Indian credit cards work for registering for Google play account. 
But for debit cards only ICICI worked for me. 
rest IDBI Bank, Bank Of Baroda, Karur Vyasa Bank, Union Bank of India did not work.
Hope it will help some of the new Indian developers who are having problem in registering for android developer account.

Comment: @shantanu: thanks for your answer, If I will open new account in ICICI bank and get debit card, then it will accepted in opening new account of developer ?? please reply me asap

Comment: Went to Axis on 1st try , opened 5k min deposit insta account , requested for Visa debit and got after 3 days. Done. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite late to answer but people are always in a search of solution ,so to those who still couldn't find their way.
The reason google wallet displays an error message saying invalid card is because

1.Goolge wallet uses international pay servie to create a developer account.

2.your card should support the international pay transaction(most of the new cards dont support in India).

**Solution:**

***Contact the respective bank's and ask them to extend the card service for international transactions***

[Note: (This is in reference to Adding Debit card )Even if the card says it has international or global access you need to activate this service from customer care of respective banks's ]

Answer (score 0):

*Most indian debit cards do not support the usage of paypal and google wallet yet! but some debit cards do!
The two banks which support both paypal and google wallet services for both credit and debit cards currently in india are AXIS bank and ICICI bank!
HDFC bank and UNION BANK OF INDIA(UBI) support these facility only on the credit cards they issue. 
All other bank currently do not have support for this facility. So i recommend the user to create an account in either AXIS bank or ICICI bank for this transaction.*